# IsReadOnly = False with issue - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem, I need some editable column in my grid, I do what I need, but when I set the `IsReadOnly` property to `False` on the grid, when loading the ItemSource, I get a *phantom* row. I already checked and the collection has the correct amount of items, is it a visual mistake?

```xml
<DataGrid AlternationCount="2"
      SelectionMode="Single"
      SelectionUnit="FullRow"
      BorderThickness="0,3,0,3"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}"
      BorderBrush="{DynamicResource GrayBrush5}"
      AlternatingRowBackground="{DynamicResource GrayBrush5}"
      HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}">

      <DataGridTextColumn Width="100"
                          Header="Code"
                          IsReadOnly="True"
                          Binding="{Binding Code}" />
```

[image]

Comment: Have you disabled `UserCanAddRows`?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Of course not :). That is the solution! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Next time please google your question first. I'm pretty sure "WPF GridView empty row" will yield sufficient results. Since this question is very likely to be closed for being *"a simple problem"* I'd recommend you just delete it.

Answer (score 3):

You should add the property CanUserAddRows="false" to delete the "phantom row".